# no fixture found error for real api stealjs

Tags: canjs, stealjs

When I build compressed javascript and css by stealjs, I got no fixture found error message for real api, not fixture url. Why it happen and how to solve?

```
// CanJS model    
can.Model("Models.ProtocolLimit", {
  indAll: 'GET /protocol_limits'
}, {});

// Rails route
resources :protocol_limits, :only => [:index]
```

The error message is:

```
fixture INFO:   ajax request to /protocol_limits, no fixture found
failed to open file  file:/protocol_limits   JavaException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /protocol_limits (No such file or directory)
Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "indexOf" of null (steal/rhino/env.js#24542)
```

Comment: Did you try making a fixture for the request with can.fixture?

Comment: No, I didn't since it is real API.

Comment: If you’re running the build from your filesystem, though, the real API is not available.